# Dell Dimension 4600i won't awaken from Suspend

Tags: suspend, hibernate

Dell Dimension 4600i with 1GB RAM. Installed Ubuntu 12.04 without difficulty. If left unattended, it appropriately goes to sleep and I can awaken it with a mouse gesture or keyboard press. However, if I use the Suspend command it sleeps and then will not awaken, forcing a hard reboot.
Pretty new install. Not many modifications from the stock distribution. I am new to Linux and would appreciate any direction someone can give.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to 2F4U on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org), who got me pointed in the right direction. Google search for "how to install nvidia drivers in ubuntu" led me to

http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

I tried System Settings > Additional Drivers but it seemed the "Nvidia accelerated graphics driver (version 173) [Recommended]" was already installed. I instead activated the "Nvidia accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (version 173-updates)". This didn't change the behavior. Still wouldn't recover from suspend.

So, lower in the above page is a [Suspend/Hibernation section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Suspend.2BAC8-Hibernation). I followed the advice to edit **xorg.conf** and **blacklist.conf** and now I can recover from suspend.